# Looping through Array of arrays in shopify-liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

this is my input array of arrays:

```
[[["MH", 50], ["XB", 50], ["MH", 20] ],
 [["MH", 50],["XB", 50],["XB", 30]] ]
```

the output array should look like this.

```
Output Array =   [['MH', 70], ['XB', 80]]
```

Basically, i want to take sum of index-1 value based on index-0 for each item of the input array. And after that in output i want only the ones with the greatest sum for each item.